# How to change android app gradle password? keystore file?

Tags: android, gradle, passwords

This info was leaked:

```
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE=...
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS=...
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD=...
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD=...
```

Can't find how to change this info for live app. Is it possible to change store or release key password and generate new store file?

keystore **file** was leaked too.

And is it possible to submit update using this leaked info? What can be done in worst case scenario? While as i understand you need to have access to the app on google play developers console, isn't it?

Comment: as long as you have the keystore file..you can replace the existing app

Comment: is it possible to change the keystore file? If it was leaked, any way to get out of the situation w/o reuploading app as *new* app?